# Java get sum dynamically

Tags: java

I have a forloop for each class and each method to get specific metrics and its exported to a csv like this

```
ClassName MethodName  No of Nodes
One       One.One      4
One       Two.One      2  
ClassName MethodName  No of Nodes
Three    Three.One     4
Three    Four.One      1
```

However I want to get the sum of all the nodes per class before I export it to a csv. Like this

```
 ClassName MethodName  No of Nodes    Total Nodes
    One       One.One      4
    One       Two.One      2            6
    ClassName MethodName  No of Nodes
    Three    Three.One     4
    Three    Four.One      1           5
```

This is what I have done so far

```
int numNodes;

for(Class cl : classes){
    for(Method m : cl.getMethod){
       numNodes = getNodeCount(m);
   }
 System.out.print(sum(numNodes));//this doesnt work.
}
 public int getNodeCount(Graph g){
     return g.getNodes().size();
 }
```

I have created a sepreate method to getSum

```
public int sum(int...numbers){

        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            result += numbers[i];
        } 
        return result;
    }
```

My question is how to get the sum of all the nodes per class before I export it to a csv.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: You keep on assigning `numNodes` for the current method in the loop which eventually will be the nodes for the last method. Are you sure that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `sum(numNodes)` uses `numNodes` that contains only the last result of `getNodeCount(m)` for the last method and the current iterated class  :

```
for(Class cl : classes){
    for(Method m : cl.getMethod){
       numNodes = getNodeCount(m);
   }
 System.out.print(sum(numNodes));//this doesnt work.
}
```

You should compute the sum for each class by initialzing `sumNodes` to `0` for each iterated class and by summing the `getNodeCount(m)` result of each method of the current iterated class :

```
for(Class cl : classes){ 
    int sumNodes = 0;
    for(Method m : cl.getMethod){
       sumNodes += getNodeCount(m);
   }
  System.out.print("sumNodes="+sumNodes)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `sum` counter per class, so you might create a map of
*String=>Integer* to store the className and it's respective sum like below

```
Map<String, Integer> sumPerClass = new HashMap<>();

for(Class cl : classes){
    int numNodes = 0;
    for(Method m : cl.getMethod){
       numNodes += getNodeCount(m);
    }

    System.out.print("Class = " + cl.getName() + ", Sum = " + numNodes);
    sumPerClass.put(cl.getName(), numNodes)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an object to store the data per class and handle your output? For example

```
public class ClassMetrics {

    private Class clazz;

    private Map<String, Integer> methodNodeCount;

    private int totalNodeCount;

    // getters and setters

    public ClassMetrics(Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.methodNodeCount = new HashMap<>();
        this.totalNodeCount = 0;

        for (Method method : this.clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            int curNodeCount = getNodeCount(method);
            this.methodNodeCount.put(method.getName(), curNodeCount); // <-- your getNodeCount method here
            this.totalNodeCount += curNodeCount;
        }

        public void printToFile(File file) {
            // implement your logic here...
        }

        public int getNodeCount(Graph g) {
            // your method
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have

```
File file = new File("somewhere");
for (Class clazz : classes) {
    new ClassMetrics(clazz).printToFile(file);
}
```

This way you break the problem down into smaller pieces and make the object (ClassMethrics instance) do the work (print to file).